# Cannot access protected property parameters laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to get the parameters from the `$request` like the following: `$request->request->parameters` but I get this error

> Cannot access protected property
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::$parameters

Now I know that with a protected property I would have to use `$request->request->parameters()` but when i do this i get the next error:

> Call to undefined method
> Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag::parameters().

I'm using Laravel V5.5

Does anyone know how can I get the parameters sent from my blade?

Comment: are you able to see data on dd($request->all());

Comment: just do $request->parameter_name example : if you are requesting name try $request->name

Comment: yes i am able to see the data if i ```dd($request->request);``` i get some tokens and the two values i need

Comment: take values like i mentioned above

Comment: if i take values i get null which is not what i get when i look inside the array if i do ```$request->request```

Comment: please show output for dd($request->all());

Comment: sorry man do dd($request->all());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I'm not sure how Laravel differs from Symfony in this case, but for Symfony, you'd do the following.)

You can't access protected parameters, that's what protected means. Instead use the `get()` method:

```
$request->request->get($parameter);
```

Or, if you want them all as an array:

```
$request->request->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

example

```
public function save(Request $request)
{
    $data['name'] = $request->name;
    $data['email'] = $request->email;
    //process $data as per your need
}
```